# Possible to change component on state change - Flex

Tags: apache-flex, components, state, transform, transition

I've got a whole bunch of data being displayed in different Labels, now I'm adding an edit state. I'd like all the labels to "transform" into TextInputs. I was just wondering if it possible to uses states to change

into something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would probably be easier to toggle between visible and invisible components on state change.

So the label lblFirstName is in the same x/y position as text txtFirstName. When lblFirstName is visible txtFirstName is not.

Shouldn't be too hard to set up.

Comment: Thanks thats what I was planning on doing, just thought I would double check first.